# prophet cross validation

Tags: cross-validation, prophet

I'm confused by the 'cross_validation' of prophet. In the following cross validation process, were parameters learned and saved to the model? is this cross validation used to train model or just to evaluate the model's performance?
Why do I need the cross validation? 
thanks

```
from fbprophet.diagnostics import cross_validation
m = Prophet()
m.fit(df)
future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=366)
df_cv = cross_validation(m, '365 days', initial='1825 days', period='365 days')
```

Answer (score 1):

Cross validation is only used to evaluate performance. This is true in general, it is not a procedure that optimizes, fits or chooses parameters. It can be confusing, because people will perform cross-validation for different sets of hyper parameters, and then use the hyper parameters that perform best, which is measured using cross-validation. So here, cross-validation will give you a measure of how this algorithm performs (although cross-validation on time series is tricky), and it may inform you decision on hyper parameters, such as whether to include holidays, custom seasonalities and so on.